# iterating over shared keys in two dictionaries

Tags: python

I have two dicts.  They share some keys.  I'd like to iterate over those shared keys.  Here are three ways to do it.

```
x={1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
y={2:'beta', 3:'gamma', 4:'delta'}

for n in (key for key in x if key in y):
    print(n)

for n in x:
    if n in y:
        print(n)

for n in x:
    if n not in y:
        continue
    print(n)
```

The first one looks like it will be hard to read in the future.

The second will have lots of indenting in the loop.

The third uses `continue` which I find to make code a bit harder to follow.

Is there a standard for what I should be using?  And is it one of these three?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best approach depends on what version of Python you're using.  They all involve using the `&` operator for set intersection.

- 3.0+ `dict.keys()` approach
- 2.7+ `dict.viewkeys()` approach
- 2.3+ `set` approach

**dict.keys()** -- 3.0+

In Python 3, `dict.keys()` returns a [`dict_keys`](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-3106-dictionary-views) object which overrides the & operator[1]:

```
x={1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
y={2:'beta', 3:'gamma', 4:'delta'}

for k in x.keys() & y.keys():
    print(k, x[k], y[k])
```

Output:

```
2 b beta
3 c gamma
```

But in Python 2, this will give you a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    for k in x.keys() & y.keys():
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'
```

**dict.viewkeys()** -- 2.7+

Don't fret, however!  This functionality was backported to Python in 2.7, but under a different name (so as not to break existing code), [`dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys):

```
for k in x.viewkeys() & y.viewkeys():
    print k, x[k], y[k]
```

(Same output)

**With sets** -- 2.3+

Since 2.3 you're able to use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), and the intersection (&) operator.

> s & t: new set with elements common to s and t

For example:

```
for k in set(x) & set(y):
    print k, x[k], y[k]
```

(Same output)

Here, however, you're duplicating the space that the keys take up (once in the dictionary, serving as keys, and once again in a completely separate `set`)

[1] [PEP-3106 Revamping dict.keys(), .values() and .items()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/)

Comment: Python 2 has [`dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys). Using `set()` is redundant there too. If you *do* need to use `set()`, do so *directly* on the dictionary, so `set(x) & set(y)`, no need to create the extra list / dictionary view object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thats a good point about the 2.7 backports, and keys, I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid indentation (though, really, it doesn't look like much) and want something clearer than the first one, you could use a set intersection:

```
for k in x.keys() & y.keys():
    print k
```

& is the intersection operator, making sure you iterate over shared keys only. If you want to iterate over all keys instead, use x.keys() | y.keys()

Comment: Ah! Of course I had missed the python 2 vs 3 difference, once again. Another good reason to use python3.