# How to efficiently get shared key subsets of multiple dicts as multiple arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

Is there an efficient way to get the intersection of (the keys of) multiple dictionaries?

Similar to [iterating over shared keys in two dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139012/iterating-over-shared-keys-in-two-dictionaries) , except the idea is not to iterate but rather get the set so it can be used to get the subset of dicts.

```
d1 = {'a':[1,2], 'b':[2,2]}
d2 = {'e':[3,2], 'b':[5,1], 'a':[5,5]}
d3 = {'b':[8,2], 'a':[3,3], 'c': [1,2]}
```

So intersection manually is simple

```
d1.keys() & d2.keys() & d3.keys()
```

but what about n-dimensional list? I feel like there is a better way than this:

```
d_list = [d1, d2, d3]

inter_keys = {}
for i in range(len(d_list)):
    if i == 0:
        inter_keys = d_list[i]
    inter_keys = inter_keys & d_list[i].keys()
```

Then getting a subset

```
subsets = []
for n in d_list:
    subsets.append( {k: n[k] for k in inter_keys} )
```

and finally use it to get the value subset

```
v = [ x.values() for x in subsets ]
```

- really the last part is formatted as `v = np.array([ np.array(list(x.values())) for x in subsets ])` to get the ndarray as:

> [[[2 2]   [1 2]]
>
> [[5 1]   [5 5]]
>
> [[8 2]   [3 3]]]

I was thinking there may be an approach using something like the numpy `where` to more efficiently get the subset, but not sure.

Comment: `where` is not an iterator.  Its arguments are arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj yes thats why I was thinking there may be a way to use it, since I am first getting the shared keys between all the dictionaries, I have an array of keys as perhaps a long 'or' statement.

Comment: Both `d` and `subsets` are lists of `dict`.  It's not until you collect the `x.values()` that you get a list of lists that can be made into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code can be simplified to:

```
In [383]: d_list=[d1,d2,d3]
In [388]: inter_keys = d_list[0].keys()
In [389]: for n in d_list[1:]:
     ...:     inter_keys &= n.keys()
     ...: 
In [390]: inter_keys
Out[390]: {'a', 'b'}
In [391]: np.array([[n[k] for k in inter_keys] for n in d_list])
Out[391]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 2]],

       [[5, 5],
        [5, 1]],

       [[3, 3],
        [8, 2]]])
```

That is, iteratively get the intersection of keys, followed by extraction of the values into a list of lists, which can be made into an array.

`inter_keys` starts as a `dict.keys` object, but becomes a `set`; both work with `&=`.

I don't think there's a way around the double loop with dict indexing, `n[k]` as the core.  Unless you can use the `values` or `items` lists, there isn't a  way around accessing `dict` items one by one.

The `sub_sets` list of `dict` is an unnecessary intermediate step.

All the keys and values can be extracted into a list of lists, but that doesn't help with selecting a common subset:

```
In [406]: big_list = [list(d.items()) for d in d_list]
In [407]: big_list
Out[407]: 
[[('a', [1, 2]), ('b', [2, 2])],
 [('e', [3, 2]), ('b', [5, 1]), ('a', [5, 5])],
 [('b', [8, 2]), ('a', [3, 3]), ('c', [1, 2])]]
```

Comment: my other numpy comment was more geared to something like recarray or how pandas dataframes can slice on column names. I guess I wish for a new python built-in that extends the intersection operator, or maybe more logically creates a new subset operator to include order for the desired dict, to not only work on the keys iterator, but also the values tied to those keys.

Comment: I worked out a way of using `functions.reduce` and `operator.iand` to calculate `inter_keys`, but it didn't seem to be any simpler than my iteration.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pandas` tools for joining columns of frames.  `recfunctions` has functions for joining structured arrays, but I haven't worked used them much.  Mostly they define a new `dtype` and array with that.  Then they copy values, usually field by field.  I suspect `dict` have more `set` like properties than these other structures.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the lists of values in your dictionaries are of the same length, you can use this approach:

```
import numpy as np
d1 = {'a':[1,2], 'b':[2,2]}
d2 = {'e':[3,2], 'b':[5,1], 'a':[5,5]}
d3 = {'b':[8,2], 'a':[3,3], 'c':[1,2]}
d_list = [d1, d2, d3]
inter_map = {} if len(d_list) == 0 else d_list[0]
for d_it in d_list[1:]:
    # combine element lists based on the current intersection. keys that do not match once are removed from inter_map
    inter_map = {k: inter_map[k] + d_it[k]  for k in d_it.keys() & inter_map.keys()}
# inter_map holds a key->value list mapping at this point
values = np.array([item for sublist in inter_map.values() for item in sublist]).reshape([len(inter_map.keys()),
    2 * len(d_list)])
# real_values restructures the values into the order used in your program, assumes you always have 2 values per sublist
real_values = np.zeros(shape=[len(d_list), 2 * len(inter_map.keys())])
for i, k in enumerate(inter_map.keys()):
    real_values[:, 2*i:2*(i+1)] = values[i].reshape([len(d_list), 2])
```

Please note that this code is not deterministic, since the order of keys in your map is not guaranteed to be the same for different runs of the program.